# Cannot resolve symbol "editText" android | binding

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm currently making an android app, and it all works. Here is my code for the first fragment:

```
package com.example.matha;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.matha.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    int correct_answer;
    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;
    private MathQuiz mathQuiz;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mathQuiz = new MathQuiz();
        askQuestion();


        /*
        binding.answerEt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    String answerString = binding.answerEt.getText().toString();
                    int answer = answerString.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(answerString);
                    System.out.println("USER SAID: " + answer);

                    boolean correct = mathQuiz.checkAnswer(answer, correct_answer);
                    if (correct) {
                        askQuestion();
                    } else {
                        //updateLives();
                        askQuestion();
                    }
                    binding.answerEt.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        */



        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String answerString = binding.answerEt.getText().toString();
                int answer = answerString.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(answerString);
                System.out.println("USER SAID: "+answer);

                boolean correct = mathQuiz.checkAnswer(answer, correct_answer);
                if (correct) {
                    askQuestion();
                } else {
                    //updateLives();
                    askQuestion();

                }
                binding.answerEt.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void askQuestion() {
        MathQuiz.MyQuestion question = mathQuiz.generateQuestion();
        correct_answer = question.correct;
        binding.questionTw.setText(String.valueOf(question.string));

    }

    private void updateLives() {
        int lives = mathQuiz.getLives();
        if (lives <= 0) {

        }}}
```

and here is my MathQuiz:

```
package com.example.matha;
import java.util.Random;

public class MathQuiz {
    int xmin = 1;
    int xmax = 25;
    int ymin = 1;
    int ymax = 25;
    int score = 0;

    int allowed_fails = 3;
    int allowed_corrects = 10;

    int correct_answer = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int questions_correct = 0;
    int questions_wrong = 0;
    private Random random;

    private int lives;
    private int numQuestions;

    public MathQuiz() {
        random = new Random();
        score = 0;
        lives = 3;
        numQuestions = 0;
    }

    public MyQuestion generateQuestion() {
        x = (int) (Math.random() * (xmax - xmin + 1)) + xmin;
        y = (int) (Math.random() * (ymax - ymin + 1)) + ymin;
        MyQuestion question = new MyQuestion();
        question.correct = x * y;
        question.string = x +"*"+y;
        return question;
    }
    public class MyQuestion {
        public String string;
        public int correct;
    }
    public boolean checkAnswer(int answer, int correct_answer) {
        boolean correct = answer == correct_answer;
        if (correct) {
            score++;
        } else {
            lives--;
        }
        numQuestions++;
        return correct;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public int getLives() {
        return lives;
    }

    public int getNumQuestions() {
        return numQuestions;
    }

}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer_et"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.412"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_tw"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:text="x * y"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answer_et"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.291" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score_tw"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Score:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lives_tw"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="210dp"
        android:text="Lives:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/score_tw"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answer_et" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm trying to make the function that gets executed when the "submit button" is pressed get executed when this little check icon gets pressed (bottom left):
[image]

I tried the following:

```
binding.answerEt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    String answerString = binding.answerEt.getText().toString();
                    int answer = answerString.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(answerString);
                    System.out.println("USER SAID: " + answer);

                    boolean correct = mathQuiz.checkAnswer(answer, correct_answer);
                    if (correct) {
                        askQuestion();
                    } else {
                        //updateLives();
                        askQuestion();
                    }
                    binding.answerEt.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But it wont work and gives 5 errors:
Cannot resolve symbol 'EditText'
Method does not override method from its superclass
Cannot resolve symbol 'TextView'
Cannot resolve symbol 'KeyEvent'
Cannot resolve symbol 'EditorInfo'

I tried a lot but i don't know how to fix this. Does anybody know a resource where the stuff like buttons, and edittext gets teached?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issue here in this part of code. Check again as to which layout you want to inflate with which view.

```
binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();`
```

I have a feeling that binding.getRoot() is not returning FirstFragment as it should. Why dont you debug and verify if its indeed returning 'FirstFragment'.